# Convert this implementation to a more efficient usage of numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Convert this implementation to a more efficient usage of numpy

Essentially for every instance D[i] <= num, I want to use that index to add numpy x[i] to nx and numpy y[i] to ny it to the new numpy array nx, ny.

```
row, = D.shape
for i in range(row):
    if D[i] <= num:
        nx.append(x[i])
        ny.append(y[i])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
mask = D<=num
nx, ny = x[mask], y[mask]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
w = np.where(D <= num)[0]
nx, ny = x[w], y[w]
```

***demo***

```
D = np.arange(10)
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)[::-1]
num = 4

w = np.where(D <= num)[0]
nx, ny = x[w], y[w]

print(nx, ny)

[0 1 2 3 4] [9 8 7 6 5]
```

---

You can also use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) to the same effect.

```
D = np.arange(10)
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)[::-1]
num = 4

w = np.flatnonzero(D <= num)
nx, ny = x[w], y[w]

print(nx, ny)

[0 1 2 3 4] [9 8 7 6 5]
```

---

***naive time testing***
*with large-ish data*

```
k = 100000
D = np.arange(k)
x = np.arange(k)
y = np.arange(k)[::-1]
num = k // 2
```

[image]

Comment: There's no real reason to convert the mask to indices, whether with `where`, `flatnonzero`, or some other tool.

Comment: @user2357112 that's what I'm learning.  My simple test demonstrates that the mask is quicker.  I am realizing via attempting to answer this question what you have just stated.